# Aitoff projection using bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a simple plot in `python` using the standard `matplotlib` aitoff projection:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(ra_rad_s, dec_rad_s, marker='o', s=70, alpha=0.1)
plt.xlabel('R.A.')
plt.ylabel('Decl.')
plt.show()
```

which gives me the following output:

[image: matplotlib output]

I wonder if there is a way of having the aitoff projection using `bokeh` instead? I want to display this on a webpage and having some of the interactive functionalities would be great.

I've learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423704/how-to-convert-a-matplotlib-pyplot-to-a-bokeh-plot) that there is no direct translation between MPL and Bokeh, so I wonder if anybody ever did something similar. I've tried some simple things (and mostly stupid, e.g. trying to add a projection keyword inside the bokeh `figure` statement) that did not work out and my python knowledge is also limited. Below is the code I have so far, without the projection:

```
TOOLS="hover,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out"

p = figure(tools=TOOLS,plot_width=1200, plot_height=800)

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'R.A.'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'DEC'
p.x_range=Range1d(0,360)
p.y_range=Range1d(-90,90)

source = ColumnDataSource(rpa)

p.hover.tooltips = [("Name","@Name")]

p.scatter("RAD","DECD", color='blue',fill_alpha=0.25, 
          size=16,marker="circle",source=source)

output_file("bokeh_test.html", title="bokeh tests")
show(p)
```

which gives the following (the underlying data is different but the purpose is the same):

[image: bokeh example]

Any suggestions are appreciated!